# Remove variable amounts of leading strings from values in a vector

Tags: r

I have a simple vector:

```
library(stringr)
a <- paste0("S", str_pad(1:360, 3, pad = "0"))
b <- sample(a, 180)
```

I want to remove all leading "S", "S0", "S00" in `b`. How to do that?

Comment: `sub("^S00?", "", b)`

Comment: Thank you. This doesnt remove the "S" from the three-digit numbers, though.

Comment: Try `sub("^S0*", "", b)`

Comment: I would suggest "accepting" @docendo discimus's answer below rather than mine, which only works for your example but doesn't really give a good answer for what's in the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

```
sub("^S0*", "", b)
```

It will replace all S at the beginning of the string and 0+ number of zeros following the S. It won't accidentally remove an S in the middle of the string.

Note that this would also replace `S000` at the beginning. If you want to limit it to maximum two zeros after the initial S, you can use

```
sub("^S0{0,2}", "", b)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this set of regular expressions:

```
sub("^0","", sub("^0" ,  "", sub("^S", "", b)))
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case since you want to remove a string easily described by the regular expression `S|S0+` you can use `sub` (from base `R`) or since you're using `stringr` you could use `str_replace`:

```
str_replace(b, "S|S0+", "")
```

There are going to be lots of regular expressions that will do the same job here, at least for the example given.

The one that most accurately describes what OP wants in general is `^S0*` given in another answer.